# QProcess won't start the requested

Tags: qt4, qprocess

I have been trying to get `QProcess` to start up an application. But I am facing a few problems in doing so. Here's my code:

```
void QOpenApp::open_now()
{
    QString program = "/usr/lib/qt4/examples/widgets/analogclock";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-style" << "motif";

    process->start(program, arguments);
}
```

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. All I get is an output message "Starting blah blah" and nothing else happens. The program does not quit and is still running but the Analog Clock (the App I am trying to open using `QProcess`) does not start up.

Comment: I tried reading QProcess documentation and in fact this example is based of the example they have over there. But that did not help. Searched for similar posts, but one post kinda like this that I found had no answers, so thought of posting this question myself here.

Comment: QProcess has `error()` and `errorString()` methods. Try to examine them before asking another similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you're giving is incorrect - I just checked on my computer, and `/usr/lib/qt4/examples/widgets/analogclock` is a **directory**, the actual executable is `/usr/lib/qt4/examples/widgets/analogclock/analogclock`.

Remember when you use QProcess, you always need to give it correct paths - it won't work otherwise.